# Alert box message to be displayed in one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert, message

In JavaScript, I would like for an alert message to appear in one line(changing the size of the alert box rather than breaking the message into multiple lines). Is there a way to do this?

This is the alert message that I'm getting right now. The contents of the message are fine. But after "Stream Definition:", which will be displayed in one line, I would like to know if there's any possible way to display the rest of the message which is the actual stream definition all in one line?

[image: Current alert message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant change the styling of the alert box by pure css becuse it is a system object as mentioned before.

I've got a few links you can check out for custom alert boxes:

[Stylish JavaScript Dialog (Alert, Confirm, Prompt) Boxes](http://www.bitrepository.com/stylish-javascript-dialog-boxes.html)
[Sweet alert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) `<-- I prefer and use this one myself. It is really simple and looks really nice in my opinion.`
[boot box](http://bootboxjs.com/) `<-- has been mentioned before, it is quite nice but a little more advanced and more code`
[a tutorial by Adam Khoury](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Custom-Alert-Box-Programming-Tutorial) `<-- I don't know if you know this guy, but he is amazing in explaining coding stuff. He has a tutorial about Custom Alert Box Programming Tutorial`

Hope this helps you out a bit. Goodluck, and if there is anything you need help with. Commnt and i'll try my best to help you out.

**EDIT:**

You need to [download the project](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/archive/master.zip) 

 then load in the files:
`<script src="dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>`
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/sweetalert.css">`
  
and THEN call the popup

`swal({ title: "Are you sure?", text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!", type: "warning", showCancelButton: true, confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55", confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!", closeOnConfirm: false }, function(){ swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success"); });`

Comment: Absolutely love the Sweet alerts. Thanks for sharing this link.

Comment: Hi, I tried using the sweet alert in one of my functions, but am not sure if I've place the code segments in the correct positions. If I have a function with if-else conditions and under each condition if I need  -> "A warning message, with a function attached to the "Confirm"-button..." from sweet alert site to show up where and how exactly am I to paste the code given in the site?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I wasn't at my computer. Can you explain what wont work? @NayantaraWilfred

Comment: I placed the entire code -> calling the pop-up, within the if condition parts in my JavaScript  function and it didn't work & I was wondering if I had to put it else where. But thanks for the above. I'll refer to it and let you know

Comment: I don't exactly get any error, but nothing shows up

Comment: sure, how about I upload the project onto github? just a  sec

Comment: Sure @NayantaraWilfred

Comment: https://github.com/NayantaraJeyaraj/Streams -> In my main.js, under the showStreamDefLine() function, Instead of the simple alerts that I've used, I'd like to use the sweet alert type that I mentioned earlier. I have not reset all the paths on my github version so it might not run but just wanted to share the codes with you

Comment: Did you download the files and included them? Because they are not _there_ in the streams folder _or_ loaded inthe index.html. This could be me being blind, but are they correctly included? And _when_ does the `showStreamDefLine` function fire? So I can test it out

Comment: If I downloaded the files. Put them in a folder. loaded them correctly and tried `<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success")
});

</script>` at the bottom of the `index.html` it showed the alert properly. But inside the function not because it isn't loaded / the streamSelect isnt shown. @NayantaraWilfred

Comment: Sorry, but at the beginning I did unzip the neccessary files and i linked them in the head section of my index.html file under scripts. But I deleted it later when I saw that it wasn't working. And btw, the showStreamDefLine function is called to action via an onchange() function on the drop down. I just found a step by step guide to getting swal working. I'll try it and let you know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The alert box is a system object. You can't modify its style. (Not easily I guess). 
If you want a customisable alert, have a look at bootbox:
http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: Well, this might work. Using modal classes... I'll try. Thanks